# CodeIgniter - Use a static IV when using AES in CBC mode

Tags: php, python, codeigniter, encryption

**Codeigniter 3.x**

Hello guys. I have a question about using IV in the encryption class in CodeIgniter. I would like to create a key based on 2 inputs. I have a Python script which we already use to create the key, but I am trying to rebuild this in CodeIgniter. I have read about the encryption class, but I am relatively new to cryptography so I don't know if what I am doing is even possible.

**Python**

Let's say I have a python function like this :

```
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

def encrypt(key, init_vector, value):
    enc = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, init_vector)
    return enc.encrypt(value)
```

Then we have 2 user-based inputs, where var needs to be 14 characters, and an integer which needs to be 2 characters:

```
var = "abcdefghijklmn"
int = "01"
```

Then we create the key, with a static key and IV:

```
key = base64.b64encode(encrypt("abcdefghikjlmnop", "the_static_IV", var+int))
```

And this results in our key.

**Encryption Library**

Now I know the Encryption library in CI is able to do this, but I am not able to use a static IV. The IV is generated randomly ( which I have read is actually the better practice ), so this approach isn't going to work. Does anybody know if I could use a static IV in CI, or am I able to generate a decryptable key with only knowing the key used to generate it? And if so, how could I achieve this?

Comment: Never use a static IV.  Just prefix the IV to the result of any encryption operations and slice it off before decryption for use.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I just re-read the CodeIgniter documentation, and it indeed prefixes the IV before the key generated by the Encryption class, which I didn't know. This basically solves my problem. Can you provide your comment as answer? Then I can mark as such.